# How to put a timer in an android dialog

Tags: android, timer, android-alertdialog

how can I put a Timer in an android dialog? I have all the dialog methods built, but I can't seem to figure out how to update the text in the dialog view every time the timer fires. my update method is already getting called once per second by another class.

here's my code so far:

```
    public class PlaybackTimerEndingDialog extends DialogFragment implements TimerCallbacks.updateTimer {
    private AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder;
    private long mTime;
    private Context mContext;
    private View mTimerEndingView;

    public PlaybackTimerEndingDialog(long startTime, Context context){
        this.mTime = startTime;
        this.mContext = context;
    }


    private void updateView(String message_text){
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        this.mTimerEndingView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playback_timer_ending, null);
        TextView messageView = (TextView) this.mTimerEndingView.findViewById(R.id.timer_ending_message);
        messageView.setText(message_text);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        this.updateView("The sleep timer will expie in "+ this.formatTime(this.mTime));

        this.mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.mContext)
        //      this.mBuilder.setMessage("The sleep timer will expie in "+ this.formatTime(this.mTime))
        .setPositiveButton("Add more time", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                TimerCallbacks.createTimer listener = (TimerCallbacks.createTimer) PlaybackTimerEndingDialog.this.mContext;
                listener.createTimerDialog();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel timer", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                TimerCallbacks.createTimer listener = (TimerCallbacks.createTimer) PlaybackTimerEndingDialog.this.mContext;
                listener.stopTimer();
            }
        });
        this.mBuilder.setView(this.mTimerEndingView);
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return this.mBuilder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void finished() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void update(long time) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //      this.getDialog().set
        this.updateView("The sleep timer will expie in "+ this.formatTime(time));
        this.mTime = time;
        Log.d("current time", Long.toString(time));
        //      this.mBuilder.setMessage("The sleep timer will expie in "+ this.formatTime(time));
    }

    private String formatTime(long time) {
        int seconds = (int) (time / 1000) % 60 ;
        int minutes = (int) ((time / (1000*60)) % 60);
        String mnStr = (minutes<10 ? "0" : "")+minutes;
        String secStr = (seconds<10 ? "0" : "")+seconds;
        return "-"+mnStr +":"+ secStr;
    }
}
```

any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put that in some function where you want to start a timer.

```
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
               updateView("fired");

            }
        }, 1000);
```

**Update**: it's the update method that inflate new layout every time, while the dialog is using first inflated layout.

Comment: thanks for your response... I may have not been specific enough. my update method is getting called once per second already. but for whatever reason my view is not changing.

Comment: How is the update method getting called?
Is it called by using a handler?  Because if it isn't call by another thread, then it will not work.
Did `Log.d("current time", Long.toString(time));` get called?

Comment: it's a callback from my main activity, where I initialized a CountdownTimer. I have logged it, to confirm that it is getting called every second. ya my `Log.d("current time", Long.toString(time));` gets called every second... so it must be something wrong with my view update method.

Comment: Yes, I think I found it.
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    this.mTimerEndingView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.playback_timer_ending, null);
    TextView messageView = (TextView) this.mTimerEndingView.findViewById(R.id.timer_ending_message);
    messageView.setText(message_text);`

After you inflated it, did you attach it to anywhere?

Comment: `this.mBuilder.setView(this.mTimerEndingView);` I think that should attach it. The view loads... it just does not update.

Comment: `this.mTimerEndingView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playback_timer_endinding, null);`
This sets mTimerEndingView  to point at new another new object. 
So you previous setView still using old one.

Comment: Remove
`LayoutInflater inflater = this.getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        this.mTimerEndingView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playback_timer_ending, null);`

Comment: But you have to inflate on createDialog though, just not every time you want to update.
Accept answer if it solves it.

Comment: so what you are saying is I just need to inflate it once in onCreateDialog or some method... then just update that TextView from mTimerEndingView.

Comment: true ture... I'll try it out.

Comment: I really appreciate you help by the way. I've been struggling with this for quite some time now.

Comment: Example:
    `@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateDialog");
        onAttachFragment(getParentFragment());
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialogfrag_addfriends, null);
        final EditText et_playerName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_playerName);

        alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);
        ....
    }`

Damn code layout in comment.

Comment: NP, I have been using this site for so long, and want to contribute back.